# How to move UILabel via taping other UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I'm quite new in using XCode and Swift, so i want to know, how to move UILabel. Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true
    drawtarget()
}

var hosPos = Int(arc4random_uniform(253)) + 10
var verPos = 580

func drawtarget() {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: hosPos, y: verPos, width: 47, height: 47))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 205/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foo(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func creatingShot(_ sender: UILabel) {
    let shot = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 217, y: 50, width: 8, height: 8))
    shot.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    shot.text = ""
    view.addSubview(shot)
}

func foo(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true
    perform(#selector(drawtarget), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
    hosPos = Int(arc4random_uniform(253)) + 10
    verPos = 600
}
```

So, I need to move shot(UILabel) to the centre of button(UIButton, that is pressed). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoLayout, just set their centerAnchors equal to each other:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myButton:UIButton!
@IBAction func moveLabelToMe(sender: UIButton) {
    myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

Notes:

- The last line of code helps to give some animation to things.
- Long-term, unless you absolutely need to use frames and CGRects, both learn and then stick with AutoLayout when possible (both in IB and code). It can be daunting to learn but it keeps things much more device independent.
- When using AutoLayout in code, remember to always set your views to set their **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** to false. This is one of the most common mistakes everybody (including me) makes.
- If you are using IB for AutoLayout, you can set up IBOutlets for constraints just like you can views.
- There are a few ways to code constraints. One is above (using **is*Active**) but another is to set up arrays of constraints which can be activated and deactivated as a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this...

Define both label and button as a global instance.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: .CurveEaseInOut,
    animations: {
      shot.center = button.center
    },
    completion: { finished in

    })
```